# Intellij: reimport SBT dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have an SBT project as a module in intellij ([link](https://github.com/vedavaapi/html-2-rest)); and I am able to run it with sbt just fine. But, as seen below, the intellij project complains about missing sbt dependencies and highlights spurious missing imports in the code:

[image]

I tried build.sbt -> reimport, but it did not work. How do I fix this in one shot?

Answer (score 1):

There are two relevant ways to add a module from existing sources:

- point to the intellij iml module file
- *add module with existing sources* by pointing to the build.sbt file

The second method correctly imports the sbt dependencies without any problem.